# Create a scrolling div with jquery masonry grid. Only works on resize but not on initial page load

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-masonry

I want to create a div that houses a jquery masonry grid inside, and has a scrollbar based on browser height once the page loads The scroll bar needs to adjust in real time as the browser is resized as well. I can get it to work on resize, but not when the page initially loads. I have tried reordering the code, and writing it in several different ways. I think masonry is disabling the scroll after all of the grid items load.

Here is the jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ucEYaJay/4/. You have to resize the browser to see the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer based on this SO question: http://bit.ly/19C4EFB

By changing this:

```
    $('.scroll-pane').load($(this), function() {
        setScrollPaneHeight();
    });
```

to this:

```
    var $scrollpane = $('.scroll-pane');

    $scrollpane.imagesLoaded( function(){
        setScrollPaneHeight();
    });
```

Now the scrollbar loads as expected. Link to the updated jsbin http://jsbin.com/ucEYaJay/12.

Answer (score 0):

Is this `$('.scroll-pane').load` function getting called?

Try putting the setScrollPaneHeight(); at the very end of `jQuery(document).ready` function

Comment: I have switched those two calls a few times, and changed `$('.scroll-pane').load` to `$(document).ready(function()`. Nothing changes. I am researching asynchronous jquery and callbacks. Nothing working so far.